# Ubuntu Mobile Installation Stuck at "The device needs to be unlocked for the following to work" Nexus 7

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

Like the title says, it just asks for my password and then gets stuck. The bootloader is unlocked.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, started in android. Then shut down, restarted the bootloader and the script started working again. Not sure what caused it to work then and not the first time it went to the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and simply removing the usb cable and reinserting then running `phablet-flash -b` again fixed it.